# Modify JQuery "Sliding Boxes"

Tags: jquery, hover, sliding

usually I wouldn't post a question like this, but sometimes you're searching for a quick fix without reading a whole book about a special programming language.

I'm using a script called "Sliding Boxes" which can be found [here](http://buildinternet.com/2009/03/sliding-boxes-and-captions-with-jquery/).

An info-box simply slides in as the result of "hovering" over an image. No big deal here. I'm trying to do is to increase the oppacity of the image from 0.5 (normal) up to 1.0 (hover). It's working well if I'm moving the cursor over the image.

[image: cursor over image]

But after the sliding box covers the image, the oppacity of 1.0 gets lost, if the cursor position is in the area of the info box.

[image: cursor over text-box]

So I need to adjust the js file, but because I didn't do anything with javascript yet, I need some help on this one.

Here's my script:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cover.boxcaptionbig').stop().animate({top:'460px'}, 
                                          {queue:false,duration:0});

    //Full Caption Sliding (Hidden to Visible)
    $('.boxgridbig.captionfullbig').hover(function(){
      $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'340px'},  
                                       {queue:false,duration:750});
    }, function() {
    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'460px'},  
                                     {queue:false,duration:750});
    });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as changing one of the animates from:

```
animate({top:'460px'}
```

to

```
animate({top:'460px', opacity:'1'}
```

Then adding the same but with 0.5 on the one that makes it back to normal again.

Without a full demo, it's hard to guess, but I assume that's all you'd need to do.